# dload:update partition MBR failed Huawei Honor 3C

Tags: rom-flashing, huawei

I have `Huawei Honor 3C H30-U10`, It was running fine but some days back when I plugged in charger it restarted and hung up on welcome screen*(no animated logo)*. Seems like I need to install Stock Rom to it.

**Phone Details:**

**Huawei Honor 3C H30-U10**
**Build Number:**  H30-U10 V100R001C900B108
International Variant

I download Stock ROM for it with version `B108` but it was in `SP Flash Tool` format. My phone isn't recognised by my laptop even though I have `VCOM drivers` installed.

This force me to think I need to download Stock ROM but which is in `dload` and `UPDATE.APP` form. It was hard for me to get any ROM `H30-U10 V100R001C900B108` in `UPDATE.APP` form. Fortunately I got one from [here](https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/3237141/+1260) (Please look at: *7. V100R001C900B108 ROM (update.app)*)

Upon pressing 
<kbd>Volume UP</kbd>+<kbd>Power Key</kbd> It successfully went to updating from SD Card but I am receiving this error log on screen:

```
md5_verify success
dloading module CURVER.....
main version string=H30-U10 V100R001C900B108
dloading module VERLIST.....
Main version from property is H30-U10 V100R001C900B108
main version check: the market is same. go to continue.. 
current version in VERLIST, allow to update. 
dloading module MBR.....
dload:update partition MBR failed
Update /sdcard/dload/update.app failed  

=============================  

   @@@@@   @    @@@  @  
   @      @ @    @   @  
   @@@   @   @   @   @  
   @     @@@@@   @   @  
   @     @   @  @@@  @@@@@  

=============================
```

My question is

1. Why I am getting this error?
2. What are the other possibilities that
   I can do to bring back this phone to life?

**PS:**
Pointing to this `dload:update partition MBR failed` Shopkeeper *(Mobile technician)* told me your phone internal memory is full, or corrupted. You can't get it right until you change the hardware part associated with memory. Is he right?

Guys, I tried hard to search this question on internet and I didn't find anything. Please provide rich information so that other community use it for reference.

**PSS:**
By going to `wipe cache partition` it says:

```
-- wiping cache
Formatting / cache...
Cache wipe complete.
```

But by going to option: `wipe data/factory reset` it says:

```
--wiping data...
```

and stuck. No further process at all.

Comment: Did you try with upload file in internal memory not external SD? This used to be a workaround for Honor 6, a few years back

Comment: @beeshyams I don't how to do it as my phone isn't being recognised by my   laptop. I will love to have any help in that regards. :(

Comment: Sorry, that's the problem. Didn't read carefully

Comment: This is a hardware (EMMC) problem.
you need to change emmc.